# IOS Parse Without TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a Parse database with classes User, Accounts, and Transactions. I want the current user to be able to display their accounts on the screen with a remaining balance. A user may have multiple accounts. The accounts class has a field called startingBalance. The Transaction class has a field called amount. I need to call the startingBalance and amounts fields to determine the remaining account balance.

I would like the output on the screen to look like this:

Checking     $100.12
Savings       $308.45

I have been trying to figure this out all week and have not even come close to displaying what I want to display. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks for looking!

Comment: what you have tried so far.. ??

Comment: What's your question? So far this is a list of requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
let query = PFQuery("Account")                                                                                                                                        
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in                                                                                                          
    // Retrieve the checking and savings balances                                                                                                                     
    var checkingBalance: Float!                                                                                                                                       
    var savingsBalance: Float!                                                                                                                                        
    if objects != nil {                                                                                                                                               
        for object in objects as [PFObject] {                                                                                                                         
            switch object["type"] {                                                                                                                                   
                case "startingBalance":                                                                                                                               
                    checkingBalance = object["startingBalance"] as Float                                                                                              
                case "startingBalance":                                                                                                                               
                    savingsBalance = object["startingBalance"] as Float                                                                                               
                default:                                                                                                                                              
                    fatalError("invalid account type")                                                                                                                
            }                                                                                                                                                         
        }                                                                                                                                                             
    }                                                                                                                                                                 

    if checkingBalance != nil && savingsBalance != nil {                                                                                                              
        // Assuming you already know the transaction locally:                                                                                                         
        checkingBalance += checkingTransactionAmount // e.g., -3.14                                                                                                   
        savingsBalance += savingsTransactionAmount                                                                                                                    
    } else {                                                                                                                                                          
        println("unable to retrieve checking balance or savings balance (\(checkingBalance), \(savingsBalance))")                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

Querying for all Accounts will only return those for the current user assuming their ACLs are set properly.